# LibGDX AStar Pathfinding on a Tiled Map

Tags: java, android, libgdx, path-finding

I want to have pathfinding in my .tmx file that created by tiled tool for libgdx but I am very biginner in libgdx. can you show me a complete pathfinding example in tiled maps with libgdx?

I use [tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/) for build my game map. in this grid map , I want to add node to every grid and connect with other nodes that it make us a graph to pathfinding .

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogohQ.png)

How can I add nodes to tiles and connect them, and how can I run pathfinding on such a graph in libgdx?

I want some thing like this : [libgdx pathfinding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9L3gyKeaE8)

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if it fits your needs, but have you seen this?

https://github.com/xaguzman/pathfinding

Its well documented. Also check bridge inside it.